# Apache server does not accept requests via port 443

Tags: linux, networking, apache-http-server, ipv6

I am running a cloud server on Apache2 on a Raspberry Pi. It is hower not reachable from the internet, as [this](https://www.subnetonline.com/pages/ipv6-network-tools/online-ipv6-port-scanner.php) Ip6 Port Scanner fails when I enter the current IP6 of the RPi:

[image]

Port 80 however works.

This is the output (on the RPi) from `sudo netstat -tpln`

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State        PID/Program name     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5900            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      369/vncserver-x11-c 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      394/sshd            
tcp6       0      0 :::5900                 :::*                    LISTEN          369/vncserver-x11-c 
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      4730/apache2        
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      4730/apache2        
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      4730/apache2        
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      4730/apache2        
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      394/sshd            
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      4730/apache2        
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      4730/apache2        
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      4730/apache2        
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      4730/apache2
```

This is from `sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -P`

```
COMMAND     PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
vncserver   369     root   10u  IPv6  14686      0t0  TCP *:5900 (LISTEN)
vncserver   369     root   11u  IPv4  14687      0t0  TCP *:5900 (LISTEN)
sshd        394     root    3u  IPv4  11477      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd        394     root    4u  IPv6  11479      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
apache2    4730 www-data    4u  IPv6 635470      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2    4730 www-data    6u  IPv6 635474      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2    4730 www-data    8u  IPv6 635478      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2    4730 www-data   10u  IPv6 635489      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2    4730 www-data   12u  IPv6 637228      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2    4730 www-data   14u  IPv6 677207      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2    4730 www-data   17u  IPv6 637239      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2    4730 www-data   21u  IPv6 677218      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2    4731 www-data    4u  IPv6 635470      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2    4731 www-data    6u  IPv6 635474      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2    4731 www-data    8u  IPv6 635478      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2    4731 www-data   10u  IPv6 635489      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2    4731 www-data   12u  IPv6 637228      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2    4731 www-data   14u  IPv6 677207      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2    4731 www-data   17u  IPv6 637239      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2    4731 www-data   21u  IPv6 677218      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2   25034     root    4u  IPv6 635470      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2   25034     root    6u  IPv6 635474      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2   25034     root    8u  IPv6 635478      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2   25034     root   10u  IPv6 635489      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2   25034     root   12u  IPv6 637228      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2   25034     root   14u  IPv6 677207      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2   25034     root   17u  IPv6 637239      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2   25034     root   21u  IPv6 677218      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2   31355 www-data    4u  IPv6 635470      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2   31355 www-data    6u  IPv6 635474      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2   31355 www-data    8u  IPv6 635478      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2   31355 www-data   10u  IPv6 635489      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2   31355 www-data   12u  IPv6 637228      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2   31355 www-data   14u  IPv6 677207      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2   31355 www-data   17u  IPv6 637239      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2   31355 www-data   21u  IPv6 677218      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2   31356 www-data    4u  IPv6 635470      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2   31356 www-data    6u  IPv6 635474      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2   31356 www-data    8u  IPv6 635478      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2   31356 www-data   10u  IPv6 635489      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2   31356 www-data   12u  IPv6 637228      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2   31356 www-data   14u  IPv6 677207      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2   31356 www-data   17u  IPv6 637239      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2   31356 www-data   21u  IPv6 677218      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2   31357 www-data    4u  IPv6 635470      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2   31357 www-data    6u  IPv6 635474      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2   31357 www-data    8u  IPv6 635478      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2   31357 www-data   10u  IPv6 635489      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2   31357 www-data   12u  IPv6 637228      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2   31357 www-data   14u  IPv6 677207      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2   31357 www-data   17u  IPv6 637239      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2   31357 www-data   21u  IPv6 677218      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2   31359 www-data    4u  IPv6 635470      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2   31359 www-data    6u  IPv6 635474      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2   31359 www-data    8u  IPv6 635478      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2   31359 www-data   10u  IPv6 635489      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2   31359 www-data   12u  IPv6 637228      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2   31359 www-data   14u  IPv6 677207      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2   31359 www-data   17u  IPv6 637239      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2   31359 www-data   21u  IPv6 677218      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2   31360 www-data    4u  IPv6 635470      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2   31360 www-data    6u  IPv6 635474      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2   31360 www-data    8u  IPv6 635478      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2   31360 www-data   10u  IPv6 635489      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2   31360 www-data   12u  IPv6 637228      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2   31360 www-data   14u  IPv6 677207      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2   31360 www-data   17u  IPv6 637239      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
apache2   31360 www-data   21u  IPv6 677218      0t0  TCP *:443 (LISTEN)
```

So the server apparently listens. My guess is it has to do with VirtulHost configuration. This is the (reduced) content of `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`:

```
Listen 80
Listen 443

<VirtualHost *:80 [::]:80>
...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
....
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf`:

```
Listen 443
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>

     ....
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is the ssl module loaded (`LoadModule ssl_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so`). In any case, a look at the apache logs would be a first step...

Comment: is `LoadModule` a bash command, i.e. a program? I get `LoadModule: unknown command`

Comment: `LoadModule` isn't a console command.  It is something that would be contained within your Apache [configuration files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32767925/apache-doesnt-load-module-from-php).  There are community tools that will help you configure Apache to support SSL/TLS.  I suggest you try one those tools to get you started.

Comment: I wanted to set up a certificate with `certbot`, but this also fails due to timeout.

Comment: Check your firewall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this did not work that my ISP provided [DS lite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_transition_mechanism#Dual-Stack_Lite_.28DS-Lite.29) which makes it impossible without additional effort to forward through the router.